# Kubernetes on google cloud with hostPath mount

Tags: kubernetes

I've been developing an app on my local laptop (Mac) with Minikube. Instead of packaging the code and files into the docker image, I use `hostPath` and `volumeMount` that points to the code/file directory on my Mac, so that I can avoid rebuilding the image every time.

Now I would like to do the same iterative testing with google cloud. What's the best way to "mount" my local code/file directory and run pods remotely on the cloud? I don't want to package the code into a docker image, push to dockerhub, and then pull from dockerhub on gcloud. My dockerhub is a free account and would expose my code.

Comment: Can you use Google's Container Registry?  I can show you how to build, tag, and upload to that.  That's what I use for Kubernetes Engine, and it's all contained in the same Google Cloud Project.

Comment: @JamWils I should be able to use that. Could you please show me how? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You want:** 
You want to mount your local file system into your remote Kubernetes cluster.

**Answer:**
As far I know, you can't do this. Its possible in `minikube`, because, you can mount your local directory with `minikube`.

**Solution:** 
I can tell you an alternative way. May be this is not what you want. But it can help you.

Do you use `git`? If your answer is yes and also if you have no problem to keep your files into git repository, following process will help you.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mypath
      name: git-volume
  volumes:
  - name: git-volume
    gitRepo:
      repository: "git@somewhere:me/my-git-repository.git"
      revision: "22f1d8406d464b0c0874075539c1f2e96c253775"
```

When you will create this Pod, `my-git-repository` will be mounted into your directory `/mypath` inside your Pod container.

Basically, you can tell your Pod to pull this git from specific branch. So every time, you change your code, push it. Then create Pod again.

Read [volumes/#gitrepo](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gitrepo)

Comment: I still need to embed my ssh key into the image to access my private Github repo. The key will be exposed on the public dockerhub. Is this almost the same as copying my private codebase into the image in the first place?

Comment: Isn't your cluster private? You can use `https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/me/my-git-repository` as `repository`.

Comment: Keep Pod yaml safe. You do not need to expose your secret into any public place.

Comment: @AinzTitor, is it suitable now?

Comment: Ah yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for the tip. One other concern: suppose I have a big dataset (~1G) that doesn't fit on Github, is there some other way to accommodate the dataset that almost never changes?

Comment: Yes, push your database into `google-cloud-storage`. Then mount it into your pod. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk . See the example, you will understand

Comment: gotcha, that solves all the problems I have. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method to replicate your setup would be to use a storage bucket for the mount point.

For your setup, just pull the code to the local host when needing to build from the storage bucket. I am assuming you have a build script to do the configuration part.

However as per the other comment, you could just use gcr to host your config files and use deployment manager to build.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for using the Google Cloud Registry:

#### Build Docker Image

`docker build -t <image-name>:<tag> <path-to-dockerfile>`

#### Tag for GCloud Container Registry

`docker tag <image-name>:<tag> us.gcr.io/<gcloud-project-id>/<image-name>:<tag>`

#### Container Registry

`gcloud docker -- push us.gcr.io/<gcloud-project-id>/<image-name>:<tag>`

Your spec will then point to the container registry path:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hello-world
      image: us.gcr.io/<gcloud-project-id>/<image-name>:<tag>
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
```